# Android camera fails on rotate

Tags: android, camera

I have this error on LGE Nexus 5 (Android 5.0.1 (android-21))

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.hardware.Camera.lock()' on a null object reference
    at video.LayRecordVideo.releaseMediaRecorder(LayRecordVideo.java:511)
    at video.LayRecordVideo.stopRecord(LayRecordVideo.java:569)
    at video.LayRecordVideo.access$3(LayRecordVideo.java:554)
    at video.LayRecordVideo$1.handleMessage(LayRecordVideo.java:249)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)

private void releaseMediaRecorder()
    {
        if (mMediaRecorder != null)
        {
            mMediaRecorder.reset(); // clear recorder configuration
            mMediaRecorder.release(); // release the recorder object
            mMediaRecorder = null;
            mCamera.lock(); // this is line 511
        }
    }
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest fix is to add `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` to your activity in `AndroidManifest.xml` file. For example:

```
<activity 
 android:name=".YourActivity"
 android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
```

It will prevent re-creating activity on configuration changes (e.g. rotating the screen). Another solution could be handling configuration changes in `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)` method by yourself in your activity.

I'm not sure whether this solution will help.

Comment: But this android:configChanges, the activity will rotate?

Comment: You will be able to rotate the screen, but Activity won't be re-created. It may fix your crash, but I'm not sure about that. You can check it.